# Azure SDK - Unable to start Tomcat from Azure SDK

Tags: sdk, azure

I was following [Azure Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/ee941631) and found error while trying to run the Azure SDK. Please refer the image below. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you service configuration, the end point is defined to be type TCP and not http.  As the emulator doesn't know what is behind the tcp port it doesn't open a browser to the url.  If it was defined as http end point it will most probably start a browser window to connect to the endpoint.

As Java won't probably never use web roles (I have only been able to find http end point pointed to web roles) you will probably not use http end point, so you will have to open your self the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 32-bit machine locally, that is why you are getting this.  It is just a warning and everything should work correctly for you locally.  Just keep in mind if you are using 32-bit assemblies that Azure is 64-bit so things may not work correctly there.  You can reference 64-bit assemblies or just run in 32-bit mode in Azure.

Comment: I aware on 32-bit issues, even it was stated in the tutorial. The problem occurred after the warning issue.